# Где место частицы "бы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> В XV столетии проложили несколько улиц и проспектов, которые **бы**
>   кратчайшими путям соединяли кардинальский дворец с храмом Девы Марии.

Мне что-то не читается...

Может,

*...которые кратчайшими путям соединяли **бы** кардинальский дворец с храмом Девы Марии*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В XV столетии проложили несколько улиц и проспектов, которые  кратчайшими путям соединяли кардинальский дворец с храмом Девы Марии.

**Мне кажется, что частица БЫ здесь не нужна**, так как сослагательное наклонение обозначает возможное, желательное и т.д., то есть **ирреальное** действие.

Сравнить: В XV столетии **было решено** проложить несколько улиц и проспектов, **которые  бы** кратчайшими путям соединяли кардинальский дворец с храмом Девы Марии.

Положение частицы в предложении достаточно **свободное, с некоторыми ограничениями.**
3.1 Место частицы бы (б) в предложении [Сослагательное наклонение | Русская грамматика](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)